# How did Michonne get her sword back?

Tags: the-walking-dead

In S05, when arriving at Terminus, Michonne is stripped of her sword.
In E03, she appears back with it, but I missed the part that she got it back.
Carrol did not pick her sword back, only Darrel's bow and Rick's watch (as far as I saw)

So when and how was the sword returned to Michonne?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[According to this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/thewalkingdead/comments/7qvk7h/michonnes_sword/dss7s1u/):

> One of the cannibals had it, and at the church she takes it back after
>   they kill them. They show it.